# PHP pull the data by button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm building a system using PHP. In this system, there are also database queries. These queries depend on the response from the buttons. At the same time, these queries depend on the data that will come from the buttons. My problem is, I have 2 buttons, one to edit, one to delete, when I press the edit button, the data from the button is correct. But when I press the delete button, the data inside is empty. But the interesting thing is that I can see if I pressed the delete button with the isset function, but I can't see the data. I'm using the same stuff on both, but I couldn't solve the problem. And I use the same logic in other page resources, there is no problem there.

The sender part =>

```
foreach($personellist as $person){ $xasr=$person->Animal_ID;    ?>
             
       <tr>
       <tbody>
                <td><?= $person->Animal_ID?> </td>
                <td><?= $person->name ?></td>
                <td><?= $person->age ?></td>
                <td><?= $person->kind ?></td>
                <td><?= $person->genus ?></td>
                <td><?= $person->vaccinations_made ?></td>
                <td><?= $person->CageID ?></td>
                  <td><button  type="submit" name="giden"  value="<?= htmlspecialchars($person->Animal_ID) ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button> 
                  <button  type="submit" name="stack"  value="<?= htmlspecialchars($person->Animal_ID) ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button> </td>
                  </tbody>          
       </tr>
       
                 
             <?php }
```

The receiver part = >

```
 $gelen1=$_POST["giden"];
 $gelen2=$_POST["stack"];
if(isset($_POST["giden"])){
    $gelen1=$_POST["giden"];
    $post=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM animals where Animal_ID=:id");
       $post->execute(array(
         'id'=> $gelen1
       ));
       $ayarcekpost=$post->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
  
     
     if(isset($_POST['stack'])){
      $gelen2=$_POST["stack"];
      $post=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM animals where Animal_ID=:id");
      $post->execute(array(
        'id'=> $gelen2
      ));
      $ayarcekpost=$post->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $sex=$_POST["delete"];
    
      $sth4 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM cages where CageID='".$ayarcekpost["CageID"]."'");
      $sth4->execute();
      $result = $sth4->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $count=$result["count_of_animals"];
      $count=$count-1;
      $sex=$result["count_of_animals"];
      $sth2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE cages
      SET count_of_animals=:coa
      WHERE CageID=:cid ");
        $sth2->execute(array(
          'coa' => $count,
          'cid' => $ayarcekpost["CageID"]

        ));
        echo $result["count_of_animals"];
        if($sth2){
        header("Location:../production/hayvan-ayarlar.php?durum='".$result["count_of_animals"]."'");
         }
         else{
        header("Location:../production/hayvan-ayarlar.php?durum=no");
         }
      /*$cc=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM animals
      WHERE 
        Animal_ID = :id");
         $cc->execute(array(
         'id'=> $gelen
         ));*/
       
        
         
         
      }
```

Comment: You should write both isset as if..else if instead of 2 if statement.

Comment: _"But when I press the delete button, the data inside is empty"_ - which data? Please share your exact debugging efforts.